# How to calculate the number of points per square in a grid of a custom size?

Tags: r, grid

I have a large dataset of individuals that are in an area. But I want to change the sampling design by separating my field or space with a predefined grid. Here is the dataset:

```
set.seed(1456)
n = 100
x=rnorm(n)
x
y = 1:n
df =data.frame(x = x, y = y, sp = sample(letters[1:5], size = 100,replace = T),stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

plot(y = df$x, x =  y, pch =21, 
     bg = df$sp,
     col = df$sp, 
     cex = .4)
```

This will create a grid of the area that I'm studying

```
xytransect <- expand.grid(seq(0, n, 5), seq(min(x), max(x), .6))
```

This is to show the "nodes" of the grid

```
points(xytransect, cex= 0.3, pch = 21, 
       bg  = "pink", 
       col = "pink")
```

This is just showing the actual grid on the area.

```
abline(v = seq(0, n, 5), h = seq(min(x), max(x), .6))
```

[image]

The idea in this is to group the species and see how many are present within a square of the grid.

I was able to group the species (here letters) based on their name on the whole area. But how can I group them on the grid that I created?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  
  group_by(sp) %>% 
  summarise(n())
```

Would it be possible to get the center of each square and colour the square by the amount of species (letters) it had inside?

That's Jason's answer. 
[image]

Comment: I am a little confused by your example. The `x` coordinate is on the vertical axis and there is no corresponding `y` coordinate. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: You're right! I forgot to put it. Here they are. The answer from Jason is giving a weird center. I uploaded his answer (plot) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited the response to use the same bin definition as in the Q.

```
ibins <- seq(0, nrow(df)+5, 5)
jbins <- seq(min(df$x)-0.6, max(df$x)+0.6, .6)
xytransect <- expand.grid(seq(0, n, 5), seq(min(x), max(x), .6))

out <- df %>% 
  mutate(i = min(ibins) + 5*(cut(row_number(), breaks= ibins,labels=FALSE)-1),
         j = min(jbins) + 0.6*(cut(x,breaks=jbins,labels=FALSE)-1)) %>%
  group_by(i,j) %>% 
  summarise(count=n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(i_center = i+2.5,
         j_center = j+0.3)


plot(out$i_center, out$j_center, cex = out$count/max(out$count), pch = 21, col ="orange", bg = "orange")
abline(v = seq(0, n, 5), h = seq(min(x), max(x), .6))
```

[image]

Comment: I've used this code to plot a point in the middle which it's size correspond to the number of "letters" in a square. Here is the code: `points(out$i_center, out$j_center, cex = out$count/max(out$count), pch = 21, col ="orange", bg = "orange")`

But it seems that the points are not in the middle and that the points are not counted properly... Do you know why?

Comment: It looks like you're overlaying the two plots. Is that what you're intending? Looking at just `plot(out$i_center, out$j_center, cex = out$count/max(out$count), pch = 21, col ="orange", bg = "orange")` looks reasonable to me.

Comment: That's what I did, but it's not centered... See the edit in my question showing your answer with an image.

Comment: @M.Beausoleil - So, for each bin, you want to plot by the x and y averages for that bin?

Comment: For each square in the diagram, I want to compute the number of points in that particular square, and have the coordinate of the center of each square. Your code is leaning toward this but not exactly showing what I was expecting. Is it also specific to the scale of the graph? I have another dataset and might not adjust accordingly.

Comment: @M.Beausoleil - I added a plot above. If you can clarify how the result of the code above differs from what you're looking for, I'd be glad to try and fix it. Thanks

Comment: @M.Beausoleil -Nevermind, I see it. You're saying we're using different ranges to define the y-bins. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer using ggplot2's `geom_tile()` to plot the tiles filled in by number of unique species found in each tile, which is what the OP requested and is different than the number of individuals per tile.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Add some excess to the limits to ensure that all points are captured,
# even those on the edges.
xcoords <- seq(min(x)-1, max(x)+1, .6)
ycoords <- seq(-5, n+5, 5)

# Determine cell index and its coordinates for each individual.
df <- df %>%
  mutate(x_cell_index = sapply(x, function(z) which(z < xcoords)[1]),
         x_cell_min = xcoords[x_cell_index - 1],
         x_cell_max = xcoords[x_cell_index],
         y_cell_index = sapply(y, function(z) which(z < ycoords)[1]),
         y_cell_min = ycoords[y_cell_index - 1],
         y_cell_max = ycoords[y_cell_index])

# Summarize the number of unique species found in each cell.
df_cellcounts <- df %>%
  group_by(x_cell_min, x_cell_max, y_cell_min, y_cell_max) %>%
  summarize(n_spp = length(unique(sp)))

# Plot it.
ggplot(df_cellcounts, aes(x = (x_cell_min+x_cell_max)/2, y = (y_cell_min+y_cell_max)/2, fill = factor(n_spp))) +
  geom_tile()
```

This produces the following plot.[image]